# Run a Alpakka Kafka Consumer on Demand in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, alpakka

When all the messages have been handled, I need to shut off the Kafka consumer until the next call. I obviously won't be able to use what I wrote. Any assistance would be greatly valued.

```
  val consumerDrainingControl = Consumer
    .mapAsync(1) { msg =>
      // Process
      Future.successful(msg.committableOffset)
    }
    .via(Committer.flow(committerDefaults.withMaxBatch(1)))
    .toMat(Sink.ignore)(DrainingControl.apply)
    .run()
  consumerDrainingControl.drainAndShutdown()
```

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49638880/6802156 can help

Comment: On what criteria should you stop consuming? No more message? A number of message maximum each time? A duration ?

Comment: Stop the Consumer once all messages have been read. In short, I want to use an API call to run the consumer.